# My useEffect hook is never triggered, not even on first load

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I have an issue where the `useEffect()` React hook in my small React app is never triggered.

When the app loads, it first goes to index.js, which then loads the Dungeon component.

So it does work in that sense.

You can see I have `console.log()` calls so I can see what is being hit and what is not.

So the app does load find at the beginng, no errors.

It does load the Dungeon component and I see the expected `generationId` being written out to the console.

The API endpoint works because I can test it successfully using Postman.

The problem is, it never hits the api, because the `getGeneration` function is never hit because `useEffect` is never triggered.

The error I get is:

```
Dungeon.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
```

The error happens because `data` is never filled by the api.

So I know why I am getting the error, but I have no clue as to why `useEffect` is not being triggered.

Does anyone see anything wrong or bad?

Here is my index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.Fragment>
        <Dungeon generationId={id} />
    </React.Fragment>,
    document.getElementById('dungeon')
)
```

And here is the Dungeon Component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

const Dungeon = ({ generationId }) => {

    const [generationDetails, setGenerationDetails] = useState();
    console.log("Dungeon Component entry :: generationId has a value of --> ", generationId);

    const getGeneration = async (id) => {
        console.log("getGeneration hit.");
        const data = await axios.get('api/generations/' + id);
        setGenerationDetails(data);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect() triggered..but it's never triggered! ");
        getGeneration(generationId);
    }, []) // Empty so it gets called only once
    return (
        <div id="generation">
            <div>
                <div id="generationDescription">
                    <div>Title:{generationDetails.data.title}</div>
                    <div>Description: {generationDetails.data.description}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Dungeon;
```

Comment: Did you made ReactDOM import in your index.js file? import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

Comment: @VitaliyDankiv yes it's being imported in my index.js

Comment: try console.log(generationDetails) , I think that generationDetails.data property doesn't exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error appears to be caused during mounting your component (adding it to the DOM tree), which occurs before the `useEffect()` is run.

The first call to your useEffect is invoked at a similar state to `componentDidMount` (subsequent calls are similar to `componentDidUpdate`). In your case, mounting the component includes displaying your title and description, and those values are dependent on having an object to grab them from.

There are at least three possible solutions:

1. Add a default object in your `useState()`.

```
const [generationDetails, setGenerationDetails] = useState({
  data: {
    description: '',
    title: 'Loading...',
  }
});
```

2. Test that the object has been loaded before rendering your JSX.

```
    ...

    return (
     {!!generationDetails && (
        <div id="generation">
            <div>
                <div id="generationDescription">
                    <div>Title:{generationDetails.data.title}</div>
                    <div>Description: {generationDetails.data.description}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     )
   });
```

3. Use optional chaining for each value (mentioned also by Ossama). The expressions will return `undefined` until your object is created, and the `undefined` values will not render.

```
<div>Title:{generationDetails?.data?.title}</div>
<div>Description: {generationDetails?.data?.description}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, can I combine both option 2 and 3 to make it more bullet proof? Also, do I need a closing `{` brace somewhere?

Comment: It can't hurt to use both 2 & 3. The second solution is worth including if you don't want your content wrappers to appear if there's no data.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use Optional chaining (?.) and a default value, example instead of `generationDetails.data.title` you can use `{generationDetails?.data?.title || ""}` .

Comment: This is the correct answer. The optional changing is the key.